# Seeking to understand Python Synta code erro

Tags: python, pandas

Seeking to understand why there is a syntax error for the following code at the first colon:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1.4, np.nan], [7.1,-4.5],
....:          [np.nan, np.nan], [0.75, -1.3]],
....:        index=['a','b','c','d'],
....:        columns=['one', 'two'])

File "<ipython-input-72-05334ff3d6ba>", line 11
    ......:          [np.nan, np.nan], [0.75, -1.3]],
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an unexpected indent on the second line after the colon, maybe remove the indent and error may go away.